# SwiftUI animated view weird transition when appears inside ZStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a problem regarding behavior of an animated loading view. The loading view shows up while the network call. I have an isLoading @Published var inside my viewModel and the ActivityIndicator is shown inside a ZStack in my view. The Activityindicator is a custom view where I animate a trimmed circle - rotate it. Whenever the activity indicator is shown inside my mainView it has a weird transition when appearing- it is transitioned from the top left corner to the center of the view. Does anyone know why is this happening? I attach the structs with the code and 3 pictures with the behavior.
ActivityIndicator:

```
struct OrangeActivityIndicator: View {
    var style = StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6, lineCap: .round)
    @State var animate = false
    let orangeColor = Color.orOrangeColor
    let orangeColorOpaque = Color.orOrangeColor.opacity(0.5)
    
    init(lineWidth: CGFloat = 6) {
        style.lineWidth = lineWidth
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CircleView(animate: $animate, firstGradientColor: orangeColor, secondGradientColor: orangeColorOpaque, style: style)
        }.onAppear() {
            self.animate.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    @Binding var animate: Bool
    var firstGradientColor: Color
    var secondGradientColor: Color
    var style: StrokeStyle
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: 0.7)
            .stroke(
                AngularGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [firstGradientColor, secondGradientColor]), center: .center), style: style
            )
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: animate ? 360 : 0))
            .transition(.opacity)
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.7) .repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animate)
    }
}
```

The view is use it in :

```
struct UserProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: UserProfileViewModel
    @Binding var lightMode: ColorScheme

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(userProfileEmail)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(.bottom, 16)
                    SettingsView(userProfile: $viewModel.userProfile, isDarkMode: $viewModel.isDarkMode, lightMode: $lightMode, location: viewModel.locationManager.address, viewModel: viewModel)
                    ButtonsView( userProfile: $viewModel.userProfile)
                    Spacer()

                }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)

                if viewModel.isLoading {
                    OrangeActivityIndicator()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
//                        .animation(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with animation nil but it doesn't seem to work.
Here are the pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try to put a clear Rectangle() with maxWidth and maxHeight to .infinity before VStack and ZStack(alignment: .topLeading)

Comment: ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12) {.... }
               if viewModel.isLoading {
                       OrangeActivityIndicator()
                           .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                           .animation(nil)
                 }
      }

I tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: it's working in this way?

Comment: no. I added as you said a Rectangle with a frame of maxWidth and maxHeight both .infinity  and background Color.clear before the VStack in the ZStack body. ANd ZStack Alignment topLeading. It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution - put it *over* `NavigationView`. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
    NavigationView {

       // .. your content here

    }
    .overlay(                    // << here !!
        VStack {
            if isLoading {
                OrangeActivityIndicator()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Nothing is changed, I have the same behavior. :(

Comment: Nice! OMG I was looking for a solution for days. Thank you. Why was that bug manifesting could you tell me please?